# Accounting for lower and uppercase in glob

Tags: python

I need to pass an extension to function, and then have that function pull all files with that extension in both lower and uppercase form.

For example, if I passed `mov`, I need to function to do:

```
videos = [file for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, '*.[mM][oO][vV]'))]
```

How would I accomplish the lower + upper combination above given a lowercase input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> def foo(extension):
...     return '*.' + ''.join('[%s%s]' % (e.lower(), e.upper()) for e in extension)
... 
>>> foo('mov')
'*.[mM][oO][vV]'
```

Answer (score 5):

Since [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) just calls `os.listdir` and `fnmatch.fnmatch`, you could just call `listdir` yourself, and do your own matching. If all you're looking for is a matching extension, it's a pretty simple test, and shouldn't be hard to write either as a regular expression or with `[-3:]`

Comment: or "blah.mOv".lower().endswith(".mov").

Answer (score 0):

You can convert strings between upper and lowercase easily:

```
>>> ext = 'mov'
>>> ext.upper()
'MOV'
```

So just use that in your function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on Unix, you can try to call this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

#replace the "/tmp/test/" and "*.test" with your search path and extension
args = ["find", "/tmp/test/", "-iname", "*.test"]
files = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()

>>> files
['/tmp/test/a.Test\n', '/tmp/test/a.TEST\n', '/tmp/test/a.TeST\n', '/tmp/test/a.test\n']
```

[more detail on subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)